# Porque el primer select me trae los casos del dia pero cuando lo hago con getdate() no los trae

Tags: sql

1- SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE  fecha = '2020-02-17'

2- SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE  fecha = GETDATE()

Comment: Que tipo de dato es tu columna fecha?

Answer (score 0):

Porque GETDATE() te trae el día y la hora.

Para tu caso tenes que castearla con **CAST** a date para que solo te traiga el día.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLA 
WHERE fecha = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Saludos.

Comment: antes funcionaba bien, con el getdate, todo viene a raiz de un cambio de servidor

Comment: Que fecha está obteniendo? Podrías hacer un: select cast(getdate() as date).

Comment: si de esa manera funciona..

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo podria ser por que GETDATE() te devolvería algo como 2020-02-17 13:42:40.247

Cuando tu solo necesitas 2020-02-17
en ese caso deberías de usar algo como

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLA 
WHERE fecha = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Tambien podrias usar un CONVERT

aqui te dejo algo de info adicional

La primera diferencia entre CAST y CONVERT es CAST es un estándar ANSI, mientras que CONVERT es una función específica en el servidor SQL. También hay diferencias cuando se trata de lo que una función particular puede y no puede hacer.

Read more: Difference Between CAST and CONVERT | Difference Between http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-cast-and-convert-2/#ixzz6EF5xc9eR